# Ruby on Rails: How to Sync Heroku app and Localhost Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, heroku

How do I sync the database from Heroku to my Localhost? I realise they are different. Why so?

Apologies for the amateur question as I am new to Ruby on Rails and am following tutorials to learn.

Comment: do you want to export your local db to heroku db

Comment: I would like the other way round. heroku to local db

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [pgbackups](https://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups) add-on, as this will give you the benefit of doing regular backups of your production database as well.

Using that add-on, you can take a snapshot on demand, then download it to your local machine.  Upon doing this, there are a number of ways you can import this locally.  I'd recommend following [Heroku's documentation on importing](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) as it is the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull your heroku database into your local machine, use:
`$ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi` and if you want to push your local database to heroku, you can use:
`heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi`, sushi being the name of your app. You can find more details about `pg:push` and `pg:pull` [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pg-push-and-pg-pull)

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't normally want to push your local db to heroku!

Comment: I have tried pulling with "$ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi" but got this error "Unknown database: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL, HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA_URL"

Comment: You can use, $ heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA mylocaldb --app sushi

Comment: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA is just a placeholder that can change depending on how heroku has named your database, and from the error it appears your database is HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AQUA.

Comment: what should be mylocaldb?

Comment: "mylocaldb" is a placeholder for your application's database name as specified in the `config/database.yml` file.

Comment: Hi @Pette, which should i use? "db/development.sqlite3", "db/test.sqlite3" or "db/production.sqlite3"?

Comment: Sorry for taking too long to respond, i've not visited this site since yesterday. You should use your development database which is "db/development.sqlite3".